# Calculating the difference between the first non-na value and the last na-value based on a grouped condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to calculate the percentage increase or decrease between the first and last non-na value for the following dataset:

| Year | Company | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | X | 341976.00 |
| 2020 | X | 1.000 |
| 2021 | X | 282872.00 |
| 2019 | Y | NaN |
| 2020 | Y | NaN |
| 2021 | Y | NaN |
| 2019 | Z | 4394.00 |
| 2020 | Z | 173.70 |
| 2021 | Z | 518478.00 |

As I want the relative change I would expect the formula to do something like:

```
(last non-na value)/(first non-na value)-1
```

This should return something like:

| Year | Company | Data | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | X | 341976.00 | NaN |
| 2020 | X | 1.000 | NaN |
| 2021 | X | 282872.00 | -0.17 |
| 2019 | Y | NaN | NaN |
| 2020 | Y | NaN | NaN |
| 2021 | Y | NaN | NaN |
| 2019 | Z | 4394.00 | NaN |
| 2020 | Z | 173.70 | NaN |
| 2021 | Z | 518478.00 | 11.700 |

I have tried to combine groupby based on the company field with the first_valid_index but havent had any luck finding a solution. What is the most efficient way of calculating the relative change as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If aggregate [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and
[`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) it omit missing values, so is possible divide values and subtract `1`:

```
s = df.groupby('Company')['Data'].agg(['last','first']).eval('last / first').sub(1)
```

Then found index values for last non missing values per `Company`:

```
idx = df.dropna(subset=['Data']).drop_duplicates(['Company'], keep='last').index
```

And mapping only matchded rows by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df.loc[idx, 'Date'] = df.loc[idx, 'Company'].map(s)
print (df)

   Year Company      Data        Date
0  2019       X  341976.0         NaN
1  2020       X       1.0         NaN
2  2021       X  282872.0   -0.172831
3  2019       Y       NaN         NaN
4  2020       Y       NaN         NaN
5  2021       Y       NaN         NaN
6  2019       Z    4394.0         NaN
7  2020       Z     173.7         NaN
8  2021       Z  518478.0  116.996814
```

Comment: Is there a way of annualizing the change? In the case above it would be done by dividing the date column by (last year - first year).

Comment: @peho15ae - Can you check `s = df.groupby(['Year','Company'])['Data'].agg(['last','first']).eval('last / first').sub(1)` and then `idx = df.dropna(subset=['Data']).drop_duplicates(['Company','Year'], keep='last').index` ?

Comment: That just returns NaN across  the column

Comment: @peho15ae - Because not exist duplicated `Year` values per some group.

Answer (score 0):

To find first non-na value u can:

- iterate from first to last element of column and break if u value is not `np.nan`,
- use `.dropna` method on dataframe and gets 1st element from the result df.

To find last:

- iterate from the last to first and (just like above),
- use `dropna` and gets value from last row